# Can't run Perl script on other computer

Tags: perl

When I try to run script on my second computer I get this message:

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0
(before "LWP will support htt...") at iptest.pl line 21,  line 2.
```

On my first computer, the script works fine.

Line 21:

```
my $data = decode_json($resp->content);
```

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Showing us the rest of the code would be a big help to us.

Comment: When reading from `STDIN`, you have to `chomp` your variable to remove the newline.     `chomp(our $qve = <STDIN>);` And I think you could use `my` rather than `our`.

Comment: Whenever you have a situation like this `Data::Dumper` is your friend. Do a data dump of $resp->constant and see what it looks like. Do one of `$resp` itself and see what it looks like. This may give you an idea why `decode_json` may be failing. Is there a difference between the Perl versions of the two machines?

Comment: Still same.. It works fine when I test it on other computer but on this it show it error.. Maybe i didn't install some module? Same versions..

Comment: Is one computer Unix/Linux and the other Windows?

Comment: I tryed alose other script with json but can't work.. No all is same,Ubuntu/

Comment: @MilosLazovic: you really need to post the contents of your JSON string or something. We can't guess what magic character is causing a problem.

Comment: I can't get JSON.. I tryed with YAML::Tiny to dump but get this ; Cannot serialize LWP::UserAgent

Comment: Could someone try on his own computer i put my API key till solve?

Comment: You need to show us what's in `$resp->content`. This isn't hard and you are making unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Like I said in last comment I can't get it..

Comment: @MilosLazovic: yes you can. Just print it.

Comment: It can't be printed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that the JSON error is the only error you get. But it does contain a tiny little hint: "LWP will support htt...". I bet that LWP is missing a module it needs to be able to make https connections. You now have two options:

1. print `$response->content` to see the full error message.
2. On the command line, do something like `lwp-request https://google.com/`. You should see the full error message.

Then install the missing module.

And of course: please, please, please:

- `use strict` and `use warnings`
- Clean that script up and throw away every `use`-line you don't need: IO::Socket, LWP::Simple, YAML::Tiny.
- Read the documentation of the modules that you actually are using. What are you trying to achieve with `LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive)`? Hint: It won't help to quote `keep_alive`.

Comment: I get this is missing module:     @ubuntu:~/Desktop$ lwp-request https://google.com/
LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module
is installed.
But for some reason It can;t be installed

Comment: I get this error : Failed during this command:
 GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz          : make_test NO

Comment: If this is on Ubuntu, you can simply install the `liblwp-protocol-https-perl` package.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

1. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.
2. Never use `$response->content`. What it returns is useless. Instead, use `$response->decoded_content( charset => 'none')`.
3. You need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the values you get from STDIN.
4. You should never use `our` unless forced to (e.g. `our @ISA` = ok). `my` should be used instead.
5. `my $format = '$format'; "$format"` is a silly way of writing `"\$format"`.

Comment: Ok, but it don't problem.Because script works fine on my other computer. Could someone try it on his computer and tell me results?

Comment: @MilosLazovic: did you try these suggestions, or just dismiss them because the script happens to work on one computer? Do you actually want to solve the problem?

Comment: @MilosLazovic: what are the new problems?

Comment: It doesn't make a new problems. It might reveal existing problems that went by unnoticed, but that's not making new problems.

Answer (score 1):

I applied most of the changes ikegami suggested. Then perl gave me good error messages to fix the remaining issues. It looks like it works now. Don't ask why it didn't work before. Your code is weird that it's hard to say what exactly went wrong. With strict and warnings you're forced to write better code. Maybe add some nicely named subroutines to add more clarity.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use LWP::Simple;
use YAML::Tiny;
use JSON;
use URI;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

print "Enter Qve:";
my ( $qve, $loc, $key, $href );
chomp( $qve = <STDIN> );
print "Enter Location:";
chomp( $loc = <STDIN> );

$key = '';
my $format = '$format';
$href =
"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query='$qve [loc:$loc]'&Latitude=43&Longitude=19&$format=JSON";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('keep_alive');
$ua->credentials( "api.datamarket.azure.com" . ':443', '', '', $key );
my $resp = $ua->get($href);
my $data = decode_json( $resp->decoded_content( charset => 'none' ) );
my @urls = map { $_->{'Url'} } @{ $data->{d}->{results} };

my @za;
for my $i ( 0 .. $#urls ) {
    my $trz  = "www.";
    my $host = URI->new( $urls[$i] )->host;
    $host =~ s/$trz//g;
    push( @za, $host );
}
```

Comment: That's the clean version of version of that code, but by no means the correct version.

Comment: Still don't work for me:    malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "LWP will support htt...") at iptest.pl line 26, <STDIN> line 2.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this fixed the issue for me (CentOS):

# yum install perl-Crypt-SSLeay

Comment: Since I didn't use the yum packages, I did "cpan Crypt::SSLeay" to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got in the same situation. After I used 'yum' to install perl, I still got the error when run the perl script.

```
$ sudo yum install perl             
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management
...
```

Eventually I did these, and it works.

```
$ lwp-request https://google.com/

It returned an error message .. (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)

$ sudo rpm -ivh ~/perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.07-4.el8.noarch.rpm

$ lwp-request https://google.com/
```

it returned a HTML page.

and my perl script can run without error.

(my system is:

$ cat /etc/os-release
   PRETTY_NAME=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 )