# Malformed JSON string when using perl and earthexplorer

Tags: json, perl, landsat

I'm currently working with the USGS's EarthExplorer to setup some batch downloads of Landsat scenes based on spatial coordinates. They provide a wonderful handy script to do this at https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/example/json-download_data-pl which is great. I'm working on a cluster, and despite installing all perl modules properly, when I run the script I get the following output:

```
Running Script...


Error: Error: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or 
atom, at character offset 0 (before "LWP will support htt...") at ./dl.pl line 182
```

This seems curious.  As way of explanation, the script starts out with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use JSON;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number reftype dualvar );
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my ($username, $password);
$username = "myusername_filled_in";
$password = "mypassword_filled_in";

GetOptions(
    'username=s' => \$username,
    'password=s' => \$password,
) or die "Error retrieving Username and Password\n";
```

and the offending bit of code is

```
    $res = $response->{_content};
    $res = decode_json $res;
```

Following very useful advice in [Can't run Perl script on other computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513774/cant-run-perl-script-on-other-computer) I have done the following:

1. Changed `$response->content` to `$response->decoded_content( charset => 'none')` in the offending area of code.
2. Ran `lwp-request https://google.com/` which just pulled back a full webpage - no error. So, that seems to be working.
3. Tried to see some debug by inserting `print $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none');` which then threw the error

`LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed.`

And, indeed, LWP::Protocol::https is installed.

I feel like there must be something simple I'm missing - something like how I defined my username and password (just `$username = "myusername";` etc., after the variables are declared) or something else asinine.

Has anyone else run into this?

---

To add output from the query below:

```
$ which cpan ; head -n 1 `which cpan` ; echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P 'make|mbuild' ; set | grep ^PERL ; which perl ; perl -le'use LWP::Protocol::https; print "ok";'

/share/pkg/perl/5.10.1/bin/cpan
#!/share/pkg/perl/5.10.1/bin/perl
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         []
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       []
PERL5LIB=/home/jb92b/perl5/lib/perl5:/home/jb92b/perl5/lib/perl5:/home/jb92b/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/jb92b/perl5:/home/jb92b/perl5:/home/jb92b/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base "/home/jb92b/perl5"'
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/jb92b/perl5
/share/pkg/perl/5.10.1/bin/perl
ok
```

Comment: Can you add the very beginning of this Perl script to the question?

Comment: Edited as requested. See also https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/example/json-download_data-pl

Comment: Please provide the basis for your claim that LWP::Protocol::https is installed.

Comment: You realise that the program takes parameters on the command line? It's not unlikely that the response won't contain valid JSON if there's an error in the request. I suggest that you print the value of `$res` before it's passed to `decode_json`.

Comment: Note that passing passwords on the command line is a security violation. Everyone on the machine can see it.

Comment: For debugging requests and responses with LWP, have a look at LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere.

Comment: Thanks on the commandline bit - haven't used this module before. Will try.... no dice.

Comment: As for LWP::Protocol::https, when I try and install it, I get `Database was generated on Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:29:02 GMT LWP::Protocol::https is up to date (6.07).` returned

Comment: Please add the output of `which cpan ; head -n 1 \`which cpan\` ; echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep -P 'make|mbuild' ; set | grep ^PERL ; which perl ; perl -le'use LWP::Protocol::https; print "ok";'` to your answer and notify me (by leaving a comment).

Comment: Done. I think we've gone beyond my knowledge of per configs, and I suspect it's that lack that hampering me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your script uses `/usr/bin/perl`, but you probably installed it using/for `/share/pkg/perl/5.10.1/bin/perl`. You need to switch which `perl` your script uses, or you need to install it using/for `/usr/bin/perl`. On phone and gotta go. Will give details later if you haven't figured it out

Comment: Bingo. Now there are other errors, but they are due to sensible things having to do with the API which is in my wheelhouse. Thanks for helping me along the path of what is, in retrospect, obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't check for errors. You should have something like

```
$response->is_success()
   or die("Can't fetch X: ".$response->status_line());
```

The problem you are encountering is that LWP::Protocol::https isn't installed.

You claim it is, but Perl is authoritative here :) It wasn't installed by that Perl, you installed it a non-standard directory without tell Perl to look for it there, or there's a permission issue.

In this case, your script uses `/usr/bin/perl`, but you installed the module using/for `/share/pkg/perl/5.10.1/bin/perl`. You need to switch which `perl` your script uses, or you need to install the module using/for `/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: `  Database was generated on Wed, 13 Sep 2017 15:29:02 GMT LWP::Protocol::https is up to date (6.07). `

Comment: Huh - and yet with your debug code: `Error: Can't fetch X: 501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) `

Comment: So? Like I said: It wasn't installed by that Perl, you installed it a non-standard directory without tell Perl to look for it there, or there's a permission issue.

Comment: Sorry, not totally following. I installed it, and other modules I installed around the same time appear to be working normally. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Fixed! That's all I got!

Answer (score 0):

*"something like how I defined my username and password (just `$username = "myusername";` etc., after the variables are declared)"*

You shouldn't modify the code to add your username and password. The way it's written, the call to `GetOptions` will overwrite them. You should use

```
program.pl --usernam myusername --password mypassword
```